# Rake tasks failing No such file to load -- nokogiri/nokogiri for Rails 2.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

My Ruby on rails application is in Rails 2.2.2 and Ruby 1.8.7.

When trying to run

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake gems:install
```

or any rake tasks,

rake is failing to complete and shows the following error:

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- nokogiri/nokogiri
```

I cannot find any solutions for this. Upgrading my Gem version is not applicable since it is in highest compatible version with Rails 2.2.2.

Following is the line referring to Nokogiri in my config/environments.rb file.

```
config.gem 'nokogiri', :lib => false
```

And when removing :lib => false from the above line, applications fails to start.

Nokogiri is already present in the system. Running

```
gem list | grep nokogiri
```

gives nokogiri(1.3.3).

Any idea what this is? I understand Nokogiri is not getting compiled, but I cannot sort out the reason behind it. Any solution for this other than upgrading the system and using bundler?

Upgrading is not possible for me now and this version of Rails is not supporting bundler.

Comment: why would you use rails 2.2.2? It is way older now.

Comment: @usmanali can't help it. Upgrading is not an option now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade Nokogiri version to 1.5.10 in your gemfile as that's the last supported version with ruby 1.8.7

Read more on it [here](http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/38243)

Answer (score 3):

Include the correct version of nokogiri, even I was facing same problem while installing paper-trail gem for ruby 1.8.7

Comment: Used Nokogiri version 1.5.10. And it is fixed now.